# How can I keep specific checkboxes checked even when they change its index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I have a component which includes a checkbox. This:

```js
const MyComp: FC<Props> = ({ question, questionIdx }) => {
    const [isCheck, setCheck] = useState<{ [key: number]: boolean }>({ 0: false })
    const handleCheckboxes = (idx: number, value: boolean): void => setCheck({ [idx]: value })

    return (
       <Box>
         <Checkbox
           checked={isCheck[questionIdx]}
           onChange={() => handleCheckboxes(questionIdx, !isCheck[questionIdx])}
         />
       </Box>
    )

}
```

I have to call that component in a place where it will be rendered within an array with a big length. Right now I am checking/unchecking the checkboxes by its index. The thing is that this component is draggable/droppable so its index will change constantly so they will lost the check.

What do you recommend me doing to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to generate an ID to use instead of the index.
If you don't have a server-side ID (or don't want one), you could use a package like [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) to generate one when the checkboxes are created.

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
model.id = nanoid() //=> "V1StGXR8_Z5jdHi6B-myT"
```

*Note: make sure to not generate a new ID on each render (see https://github.com/ai/nanoid#react).*